# Two variables in for loop using Swift

Tags: swift, swift2, swift-playground

How to use two variables in for loop?

```
for j,k in zip(range(x,0,-1),range(y,-1,-1)
```

I want to implement this in Swift.

Comment: Put the j, k into parentheses (j, k)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your `range` is a python function, then the Swift-y solution will be:

```
    let x = 100
    let y = 99

    let rx = reverse(0...x)
    let ry = reverse(-1...y)

    for (j,k) in zip(rx, ry) {
        println(j, k)
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

if you're looping over a dictionary you can loop like this

```
for (key,value) in dictionary {
}
```

if an array etc. you're going to have to use a c style for loop
just sub in whatever start and end indices you need

```
for var j = 0 , k = 0; j < 10 && k < 10; j++ , k++ {
}
```

EDIT

missed the zip in there. You can loop like this

```
for (j,k) in zip(range1, range2) {
}
```

Comment: Didn't know about this syntax. But note: `C-style for statement has been removed in Swift 3`